# What is a good way to filter a model and display that as a table in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, datatables

I have been struggling on finding a simple method for displaying a filtered model on a Django webpage. I am using DataTables for my tables.

Here is some code for my view that filters a value and creates a serialized json. I am not sure of another method to do this, but intuitively it made sense to transform the filtered model and send it over to the webpage in the 'context' parameter.

```
def site(request, site_name):

    filtered = Participant.objects.filter(site_name=site_name).all()
    serialized = json.loads(serialize('json', filtered))

    return render(request, 'site.html', context={'site': site_name, 'filtered': serialized})
```

Here's my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-table').DataTable( {
        data: JSON.parse(filteredData),
        lengthMenu: [[25, 50, 100, -1], [25, 50, 100, "All"]],
        pageLength:  50,
        responsive: true,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: false,
        bSearchable: true,

        columns: [
             {"data": "some_data"},
        ],
      
    } );
} );
```

And here's where I pass the in the filteredData variable in my HTML:

```
<script>
    filteredData = "{{filtered}}"
</script>
```

This does not work as I am not really sure how DataTables handles JSON files. I presume that the solution is simple, but I am quite new to Django. Thank you!

Comment: "_I am not really sure how DataTables handles JSON files_" - It's easier (in my opinion) to handle JSON _Ajax responses_ rather than JSON _files_.  There are various [official examples](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/index.html) you can look at. The general approach is: (1) Your Django application provides the web page containing the DataTable. (2) The `ajax` option in the DataTable is automatically triggered by `$(document).ready(...)` when the page loads.

Comment: (3) Your Django provides a separate endpoint which provides the JSON response (this is a different URL from the endpoint used to load the web page itself). There are other ways - for example: your Django app loads the web page including the HTML table, _pre-populated_ with its data. See [HTML (DOM) sourced data](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/dom.html)... and other ways too. But your question does specifically mention JSON.

Comment: If you want to stick with your approach as shown in the question, can you clarify (a) what you mean by _doesn't work_? Any errors? And can you (b) show a sample of the JSON so we can understand its structure and data?

Comment: Hey Andrew, thanks for your continued help! I don't mind changing my approach to an Ajax response. I am willing to do whatever the simplest solution is that allows me to display pre-filtered model data in a table. Would you know a method to pass the filtered model into the webpage with Ajax?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it! The serialized JSON that is generated from serializing a filtered model is not the correct format. I had to change my booleans to strings before I passed the JSON string to my site. I could have also changed the booleans to lowercase (e.g., False -> false) since JavaScript syntax is uncapitalized unlike Python.

```
def site(request, site_name):

    site_pguids = Participant.objects.filter(site_name=site_name).all()
    serialized = str(json.loads(serialize('json', site_pguids)))
    serialized = serialized.replace("False", "'False'")
    serialized = serialized.replace("True", "'True'")

    return render(request, 'site.html', context={'site': site_name, 'filtered': serialized})
```

Then, in my JavaScript I simply replaced the single quotes with double quotes and it worked.

```
data: JSON.parse(filteredData.replace(/'/g, '"')),
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your starting point, the **least amount of work** for you is *probably* as follows:

---

**The JSON Data**

Your JSON string is as follows (based on a comment in another answer):

```
"[{'model': 'participants.participant', 'pk': 5533, 'fields': {'pGUID': 'somedata', 'site_name': 'somedata', 'fb_email': 'somedata', 'is_authorized': False}}]"
```

But that is not a string containing valid JSON.

Valid JSON would be this:

```
[{
    "model": "participants.participant",
    "pk": 5533,
    "fields": {
        "pGUID": "somedata",
        "site_name": "somedata",
        "fb_email": "somedata",
        "is_authorized": false
    }
}]
```

Note the use of double-quotes - not single quotes. Note the use of `false` not `False`.

---

**The JavaScript**

If you write this as a string, you need to end up with the following JavaScript:

```
var filteredData  = '[{"model": "participants.participant","pk": 5533,"fields": {"pGUID": "somedata","site_name": "somedata","fb_email": "somedata","is_authorized": false}}]'
```

Note that the entire string is enclosed in single quotes, so as to not interfere with the double-quotes inside the JSON itself.

You therefore need to ensure your JavaScript placeholder is this:

```
filteredData = '{{filtered}}';
```

I can't comment on the best way for you to create that `{{filtered}}` string in your Django app. Sorry, I don't use Django.

---

**A Demo**

But once you have that string correctly passed to your web page, then you can use it as follows. In the following demo, I have just hard coded the string, instead of using `{{filtered}}`:

```js
/*
what the json should look like:
[{
    "model": "participants.participant",
    "pk": 5533,
    "fields": {
        "pGUID": "somedata",
        "site_name": "somedata",
        "fb_email": "somedata",
        "is_authorized": false
    }
}]
*/

// your JSON as a string, provided by Django:
var filteredData = '[{"model": "participants.participant","pk": 5533,"fields": {"pGUID": "somedata","site_name": "somedata","fb_email": "somedata","is_authorized": false}}]';

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#my-table').DataTable({
    data: JSON.parse(filteredData),
    lengthMenu: [
      [25, 50, 100, -1],
      [25, 50, 100, "All"]
    ],
    pageLength: 50,
    responsive: true,
    processing: true,
    serverSide: false,
    searchable: true,

    columns: [{
        data: "model",
        title: "Model"
      },
      {
        data: "fields.pGUID",
        title: "GUID"
      },
      {
        data: "fields.is_authorized",
        title: "Authorized?"
      }
    ],
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="my-table" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
    </table>

  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

In the above code, you can see how to refer to the different fields in your JSON:

```
data: "model"
data: "fields.pGUID"
data: "fields.is_authorized"
```

...and so on.

I added the `title` options as well, to give your table some headers.

---

**An Alternative**

I would prefer the approach where you have a Django endpoint which serves the correct JSON (as JSON, not as a string) and provides that directly to the DataTable using an [Ajax data source](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html).

But that is probably more work, given your starting point.

There is certainly nothing wrong with your approach - it's a matter of preference. So, maybe get your current approach working first, and then decide if you want to try a different approach, after that.

Comment: Good news - you have a working solution!

Comment: For the Ajax alternative, I have the full model set up as a data source using the GET option. How would I go about serving a filtered JSON to the DataTable in the future?

Comment: You can ask a new question, if you are stuck at a specific step.